# nginx + fcgiwrapper sporadic Prblem: Delivers application/octet-stream instead of text/plain

Tags: http, nginx, content-type, fastcgi, plaintext

I am new to this forum. This is my first question.

I have a nginx-server + fcgiwrapper set up to run Programs on user request (no PHP).

For testing I have a simple bash script, which displays the environment variables and sets two cookies, a second bash-script prints "Hello World" as text/plain and another bash-script prints "Hello World" as text/html.

Another Program written in C is supposed to read Text from stdin, parse it and print Text based in the input to stdout, which the should be displayed as text/plain in the requesting webbrowser. (the requesting browser needs to use POST).

However sometimes it displays the returned text as "text/plain" (which it should do), but sometimes the browser wants to download the returned text, as if it was "application/octet-stream".

But, if I test the C-Program in a prepared Environment

```
Environment Variables:
CONTENT_LENGTH=30
REQUEST_METHOD=POST
HTTP_COOKIE=NAME=TEST; ID=200
```

it works every time, shows no errors and at the beginning it prints:

```
Content-type: text/plain (plus two newlines)
```

I have found that depending on the contents length it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. (This only happens when the program is started through a webbrowser.)
In Firefox, using the dev-tools, I could see that the answers Content-type was

```
application/octet-stream
```

and if I save it, it turns out to be a text file which contains the text that should have been displayed in the browser directly.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I have already searched for similar problems with no success
+ all other things work perfectly
+ This also happens with different browsers (epiphany, lynx, internet explorer on Windows)

Comment: If I change the C program to output `Content-type: text/html` it works.
But I want `Content-type: text/plain`!

Comment: within a location block set "default_type text/plain;"

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
If I do what you suggested (setting `default_type text/plain` in nginx.conf), the error still presists.
But, If I look into the downloaded document, there are control characters which shouldn't be there: `^Q or (iso) DC1`. Could this be the problem?
Extract from nginx.conf:
`include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
#default_type application/octet-stream;
default_type text/plain;`

Or do I need to add `text/plain` in mime.types?

Comment: In /conf there is a mime.types file you can play with, however when you download something binary text/plain is going to show you garbage, you can't mix&match, its one or the other. If you are building a backend then within the backend you need to set the proper type before delivering the content.

Comment: Ok. I have done that. However it seems like my changes have no effect.
It seems like nginx or fcgiwrapper (I am still pretty new to these) sometimes just ignore the line `Content-type: text/plain` printed by the C-program.

Comment: If you program always generate that header then you should remove the content config line from nginx.conf. Also use "curl -h" as a commandline tool to see what is actually send in the headers and by who.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through trial and error (with curl + firefox-dev-tools) I have found, that the character

> 0x11

in combination with:
`Content-type: text/plain`
makes nginx deliver `Content-type: application/octet-stream` .

I don't know why this happens, but i found that the C-program produces the error, because it prints `0x11` or `^Q` or `dc1`.
This phenomenom also happens with files containing this character.

Comment: This happens because somewhere binary is send while the sender is telling the receiver it's plain text. Which looks like the sender is at fault sending the wrong type. In the case of a proxy/nginx it might be that nginx is attempting to be smart by detecting binary data and changing the header accordingly, but thats a guess ATM.

Comment: The sender is the programm started by fcgwirapper, isn't it?
Also, I have found an error in my C program. It now no longer sends `^Q`
→ The requesting browser no longers tries to download the output
→ It's always text/plain so it works